# bash script not picking up environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a strange situation where I'm using zsh full-time, and any bash scripts I run are not picking environment variables properly. Obviously I don't expect bash to pick up env vars that are defined in zsh's environment, so I *am* using `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`, but that doesn't work either.

For example, here's a test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $MYTEST
```

I've added this line to both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` to cover my bases:

```
export MYTEST="hello"
```

I just get a blank line when running the script.

PS: I know running `. ./testscript` will work, but that's not an option since it's a system-wide script that's failing to pull env vars.

Comment: System-run scripts don't run your user-specific initialization files.

Comment: Then why does `bash -c 'echo $LESS'` show my `less` options? But other vars do not work?

Comment: Manually running `bash -c` from a shell session of yours isn't a system-run script. That's still running bash as you. But if you have variables in your `.bashrc`/etc. files that don't work that way (while `$LESS`) does then something about your init files is incorrect (or you aren't using `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` correctly).

Comment: Also, neither `.bashrc` nor `.bash_profile` is used for the non-interactive shell that runs a script. As your answer indicates, `LESS` was being picked up from the environment inherited from `zsh`, not the `bash` configuration files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops. Maybe I should try having `export VAR=val` in my `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/vars.zsh` instead of just `VAR=val`!

Comment: At first I was like "what, how is this answer even helpful?! I don't possibly ...oh, oh, I forgot the `export` as well, aaaaand now it's fixed" - Thanks!!